# Can you tell at a glance that a limit doesn't exists without graphing and much computation?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> **Problem**: From this trig function. Is there an easier way of identifying that this doesn't have a limit? $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^3}{x^4}$$

> $$
> \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^3}{x^4}
> = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x^3}{x^3} \cdot \frac1x
> = 1\cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x
> $$ which does not exisit.

I don't even understand how this was calculated. That's why I'm asking if there are any tips you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, the heuristic here is that:
$$\sin(x^3) \approx x^3$$
when $x \approx 0$ (that is, when $x$ is *near* $0$). So:
$$\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^4} \approx \frac{x^3}{x^4} = \frac{1}{x}$$
when $x$ is near $0$. Now, what they've done is to realize that:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
and since $x^3 \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, it follows that:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3} = 1$$
On the other hand:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}$$
does not exist. So, the limit of that product cannot exist. That's the reasoning they've used. A much nicer way of seeing this is as follows. Suppose that the given limit did exist. Then:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^4} = L$$
Now, we see that:
$$1 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^4} \cdot x = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^4} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} x = L \times 0 = 0$$
This is impossible. So, the given limit does not exist.

Comment: Fixed the typo :D

Comment: thank you! really appreciate the detailed explanation. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation in purple follows the exact same intuition I would personally use to see the limit doesn’t exist. In limit problems it’s good to have a feel for the *asymptotics* (or “asymptotic behaviour”) of the functions you’re dealing with. I know that for $x\to0$, $\sin x\sim x$ so $\sin x^3$ acts like $x^3$ (is of “order” $3$) whereas the denominator is clearly of order $4$, so I can tell at a glance that the denominator wins, so we have a division-by-zero divergence in the limit.

The formal derivation uses this idea more or less exactly as I describe. They split $x^4$ into $x^3\cdot x$, and use the fact that $\sin u/u\to1$ as $u\to0$ and the remaining $1/x$ term doesn’t have a limit.

Comment: thank you!!!! It really helped me.